# Perl Website with Dancer2 - how can I log user activity, history, etc?

Tags: perl, logging, dancer

We have a perl web interface that I am currently working on to slowly convert to using Dancer 2 and PSGI instead of our slow old plain vanilla CGI model.

In our old model, we stored *everything* in sessions -- the history of what the users did, the call stacks, the data inputs, ........ you get the idea.

We do *not* want to do it that way anymore so that we can keep the sessions small and efficient.  BUT, we'd still like to log just what the users have been doing (that way when an error gets reported we can see what they did to get to the error, what input(s) they put in, etc).

I looked at [Logging](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Cookbook.pod#Logging) on Dancer2 documentation, but this doesn't seem to quite get to what we need - this would only record Dancer2 messages + what other messages I put in. 
This one that I found [Dancer2::Logger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2%3a%3aLogger%3a%3aFile) doesn't seem to quite cut it either.

What other libraries could I use to do what I need? I seriously doubt that perl does NOT have somethign that does this so...

Comment: You want to log everything, without having to actually call a logging function/method?

Comment: Oh no, I'd like to know what the best way to log is. There's got to be a module out there that does what I need already so all I'd have to do is call something in that module. Dancer 2's logging stuff isn't extensive as far as I can tell to log what I need though.

Comment: You can log everything using `log_level: core` in the configuration file. It logs all the activity, pretty much everywhere. Plus you can use `log` at the spplication point you want logged too. (I know this is probably too late to help you, but it could help someone else coming here for help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, I can think of [Log::log4perl](https://metacpan.org/release/Log-Log4perl) and [Log::Dispatch](https://metacpan.org/release/Log-Dispatch), though there are myriad others.

You can use them to establish your own log files, separate from dancer's log.

As for the best way, most logging interfaces have the same api for logging, but differ in run-time instantiation, and configuration syntax. So read the docs on a few of them and maybe try a couple out on for size.

Comment: I think log4perl looks very good -- are there others that you'd recommend? Performance will be a key thing for us, by the way -- our old CGI method of keeping everything in sessions was rather pathetically slow so...

Comment: There are lots of ways to speed logging. Some are dependent on which http server you're using (there are some stupid apache tricks that one can do), but mostly, once the logs are open, when you call a logging method, you get some configurable decoration (timestamp, etc.) and then a print to a file.